# Does Sharepoint allow IFS formula

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, if-statement

I tested this on excel but can not translated to Sharepoint. 
I am trying to test for example if Column C has date that is greater than the one in column D = Submitted on time, if column C's date is less than the one in Column D than item was submitted late, but in some cases column D will be blank I want it to return Pending.

```
=IF(D5="","Pending Submission",IFS(C5>D5,"Submitted on time",C5<D5,"Late"))
```

Comment: This is the complete formulate I am using in Excel =IF(D5="","Pending Submission",IFS(C5>D5,"Submitted on time",C5<D5,"Late"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `IF` function is supported in SharePoint formulas, but the `IFS` is not.  But you can create a deeply nested `IF` condition where another `IF` function is used the third parameter (the "else" condition), so using the formula you presented you can achieve the same with:
`=IF([SubmissionDate]="","Pending Submission",IF([DeadlineDate]>[SubmissionDate],"Submitted on time",IF([DeadlineDate]<[SubmissionDate],"Late")))`

Comment: Awesome thank you for the help this worked.